# usage of prefix multi

Tags: word-usage, prefixes

Is possible to use the prefix multi in combination with an adjective that describes time frequency? 
More in detail, does "multi-daily solution" mean "a solution that spans multiple days"?
Is there a better way to express the concept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use 'multi-' to prefix a noun, not an adjective.

So you would say *a multi-day solution*.

Apart from that, you are perfectly correct in suggesting that *multi-* can be used to cover timespans.

Comment: Quite true. But it's still ambiguous whether a "multi-day solution" refers to a solution that takes several days to *design and/or implement* or one that will *[temporarily] solve the problem* for many days.